# Tab width when reading from file

Tags: c, linux, text

I'm using `<ncurses.h>` library for a simple program in terminal. It reads a file character by character in a conventional way:

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) { /* process c */ }
```

The characters are put inside an array of chars. I need to know the (y,x) coordinates of each character on terminal screen. To do so, I keep indexes that determine the first and last char in line on screen in another array. It's easily adjustable when the terminal window is resized - each line consists of either `max_x` characters, or a smaller number of characters, if there's a `'\n'`.

Tabs cause a problem - although they are recognised as `'\t'`, their width and therefore number of "pixels" in text interface is different (when displayed by `cat` in terminal or as a consecutive char in a string containing all the characters from file). However, when separated from the rest of file by:

```
if (c == '\t') {...}
```

they do not differ. I've also tried printing those detected tabs and comparing the cursor's position to get their width, but once again they look the same.

How to get the actual width of a tab when reading a file? I'd like to convert the width to a number of spaces. Thank you for attention and perhaps hints.

Comment: Are you looking for the default tab width, or the tab width as (possibly) redefined by the system's settings?

Comment: Tabs are always interpreted by the program that's displaying the text on the screen.  There is no way to determine what the author of the text intended except to guess different tab locations (standard widths) and stop when the text "looks right."  The historical standard on most systems is 8 characters.  But most editors let you select a default.  I've seen code with 2, 3, 4, and 8 character default tab widths.  Of course people can choose whatever they want.

Comment: Take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52795/setting-tab-width-in-c-output-in-bash and http://linux.die.net/man/3/set_tabsize on how to set change the tab size and how it all fits together

Comment: maybe you want to use `readline` library which does handle tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the actual tab width is dependant on the way you are presenting it on screen. For the classical presentation, that is a tabulation every eight column, you have to keep track on the `column` number where the tab occurs. You can then use:

```
tab_width = 8 - column % 8
```

Where `column` starts counting at 0 for the first column.

Comment: This would be the correct thing for Linux source code for example. But you can set an editor or display program to have "tabsize=3" or "tabsize=16" if you like.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes. That’s why I say this is intended “For the classical presentation, that is a tabulation every eight column”.

Comment: Thank you for help. This is what I needed! I forgot to add that I want my output to be displayed the way `less` does it. Keeping to this formula does the trick for Linux source codes, that are my main concern.